# selecting record with max usage date or most recent date stamp

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to extract the most recent record by date from e.g. table sample below but for ALL mobile numbers in the table:

```
USAGE_DATE  MOBILE_NO   IMEI
06-SEP-16   7464924435  3534500646600000
01-SEP-16   7464924435  0000000000000000
10-OCT-16   7464924435  3534500646600000
```

Unfortunately as a novice I have been unable to correctly update the SQL below with a select sub query to achieve this based on reading the existing answers/examples on the site - can anyone please help!?

```
select max(usage_date_time) AS USAGE_DATE, mobile_no, imei
from gsm_usage
--where mobile_no = '07464924435'
group by usage_date_time, mobile_no, imei
```

Comment: Hi, im using Oracle sql developer version 4.0 :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select max(usage_date_time) AS USAGE_DATE, mobile_no, imei
from gsm_usage
--where mobile_no = '07464924435'
group by mobile_no, imei
```

You don't have to group by something in an aggregate function.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.. your suggestion has brought back below 3 records now - apologies I failed to highlight in the original sample data that there can be different IMEIs I just need the record with the most recent date :                                                                                                           USAGE_DATE MOBILE_NO IMEI
30-OCT-17 7464924435 3553960746560000
07-NOV-17 7464924435 0000000000000000
06-DEC-16 7464924435 3534500646600000

Answer (score 0):

If you need  max(usage_date)
     the  you don't need  insert  this column in group by

```
  select max(usage_date_time) AS USAGE_DATE, mobile_no, imei
  from gsm_usage
  where mobile_no = '07464924435'
  group by mobile_no, imei
```

you must set in group by the columns not involved  in aggregation function

and if you don't want group by imei then  remove form select and grup by

```
  select max(usage_date_time) AS USAGE_DATE, mobile_no
  from gsm_usage
  where mobile_no = '07464924435'
  group by mobile_no
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.. your suggestion has brought back below 3 records now - apologies I failed to highlight in the original sample data that there can be different IMEIs I just need the record with the most recent date :                                                                                                           USAGE_DATE MOBILE_NO IMEI
30-OCT-17 7464924435 3553960746560000
07-NOV-17 7464924435 0000000000000000
06-DEC-16 7464924435 3534500646600000

Comment: answer updated  . . hope is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You would normally use window functions:

```
select gsm.*
from (select gsm.*, row_number() over (partition by mobile_no order by usage_date_time desc) as seqnum
      from from gsm_usage gsm
     ) gsm
where seqnum = 1;
```

This is not an aggregation issue, but simply an issue of identifying the most recent record.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply Gordon :) unfortunately I am getting error:

Comment: Also I didn't make it clear in the original sample data - that there can be different IMEIs for a mobile_no please see my replies to the other answers which may explain better and shows 3 records are still coming back and not the most recent by date only, thanks again for your help.